# Array List implementation with 2 threads having following conditions

Tags: java, collections

**use 2 threads, 1st thread will display the Array List items in forward order, and 2nd
thread will display the List items in reverse order.**

Comment: Although homework questions are allowed, it is not appreciated dumping the question without some effort for doing it yourself.

Comment: I want better solution. I am giving my solution to you.

Comment: @Nfear Check the solution please.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException,    ClassNotFoundException{
    ArrayListThred Alt = new  ArrayListThred();
    Alt.start();
    Thread th =new Thread (new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
            System.out.println("Starting ArrayListThred 2 "  );
            ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();//creating arraylist  
            al.add("Ravi");//adding object in arraylist  
            al.add("Vijay");  
            al.add("Ravi");  
            al.add("Ajay");  

            for(int i=(al.size()-1); i>=0;i--)
            {
                System.out.println(al.get(i));  
            }
    }
    });
    th.start();
    }
}
class ArrayListThred extends Thread
    {
        Thread t;
       // int number = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        static int total;

        public ArrayListThred() {
           System.out.println("Creating ArrayListThred... ");
        }
        public void run()
        {
            ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();//creating arraylist  
            al.add("Ravi");//adding object in arraylist  
            al.add("Vijay");  
            al.add("Ravi");  
            al.add("Ajay");  
            Iterator itr=al.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){  
             System.out.println(itr.next());  
            }
        }
    public void start ()
        {
           System.out.println("Starting ArrayListThred "  );
           if (t == null)
           {
             // t = new Thread (this, number);
               t = new Thread(this);
              t.start ();
   }
   }
}
```